# jquery animation wrap vs append

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery:

```
        var container = $(this),
            list = container.children('ul'),
            wrapper = $('<div class="wrapper"></div>');

        list.wrap(wrapper);

        var top = 0 - list.height();
        wrapper.animate({ 'top':  top + "px" }, options.animationSpeed, function () {
        });
```

but this doesn't animate the wrapper, however, if I use the following instead of `.wrap`

```
        container.append(wrapper.append(list));
```

the animation will work.

Why does the second version work but the first version doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the markup of `wrapper` is copied into the DOM and the list is appended to the copy, not to the original `wrapper` object, which remains outside of the DOM.

Explicitly referring to the list's new parent should solve your problem:

```
list.parent().animate({
    top: top + "px"
}, options.animationSpeed, function() {
});
```

Comment: ah so wrapper doesn't use the object but the html, ok that makes sense then will accept when it lets me